# Understand Python error message and resolve

Tags: python

I am not a Python programmer, but the make script is using some Python. And here I got this error message, I can see a stack trace. But how to track the problem from here?

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 ./config/pythonpath.py -I./config ./config/expandlibs_exec.py --depend .deps/libjs_static.a.pp --target libjs_static.a --extract -- /usr/local/bin/ar cr libjs_static.a bignum-dtoa.o bignum.o cached-powers.o diy-fp.o double-conversion.o fast-dtoa.o fixed-dtoa.o strtod.o jsalloc.o jsanalyze.o jsapi.o jsarray.o jsatom.o jsbool.o jsclone.o jscntxt.o jscompartment.o jsdate.o jsdbgapi.o jsdhash.o jsdtoa.o jsexn.o jsfriendapi.o jsfun.o jsgc.o jscrashreport.o jsinfer.o jsinterp.o jsiter.o jslog2.o jsmath.o jsmemorymetrics.o jsnativestack.o jsnum.o jsobj.o json.o jsonparser.o jsopcode.o jsproxy.o jsprf.o jsprobes.o jspropertycache.o jspropertytree.o jsreflect.o jsscope.o jsscript.o jsstr.o jstypedarray.o jsutil.o jswatchpoint.o jsweakmap.o jsworkers.o jswrapper.o jsxml.o prmjtime.o sharkctl.o ArgumentsObject.o ScopeObject.o Debugger.o GlobalObject.o ObjectImpl.o Stack.o String.o BytecodeCompiler.o BytecodeEmitter.o FoldConstants.o NameFunctions.o ParallelArray.o ParseMaps.o ParseNode.o Parser.o SPSProfiler.o TokenStream.o TestingFunctions.o Profilers.o LifoAlloc.o Eval.o MapObject.o RegExpObject.o RegExpStatics.o RegExp.o Marking.o Memory.o Statistics.o StoreBuffer.o StringBuffer.o Unicode.o Xdr.o ExecutableAllocator.o PageBlock.o YarrInterpreter.o YarrPattern.o YarrSyntaxChecker.o YarrCanonicalizeUCS2.o ExecutableAllocatorPosix.o OSAllocatorPosix.o jsperf.o pm_stub.o HashFunctions.o SHA1.o
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./config/pythonpath.py", line 56, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "./config/pythonpath.py", line 48, in main
    execfile(script, frozenglobals)
  File "./config/expandlibs_exec.py", line 322, in <module>
    main()
  File "./config/expandlibs_exec.py", line 311, in main
    ret = subprocess.call(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [libjs_static.a] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/priv
```

Comment: I think you should ask whoever's make script this is.

Comment: The python script is trying to run an external command, and that command is not found.

Comment: Meta comment: Please don't use `back ticks` for every 'code-ey' word, it makes your question hard to read.

Comment: Do something like `print args` before line 311 of `config/expandlibs_exec.py` to see what it's trying to execute, and check the program exists, and is in your `$PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

The first step would be to look into the source code; Python prints the file name and line number: `File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249`

When you look there, you'll see some code. The next step would then be to find out where each variable is assigned (i.e. who sets `child_exception`) and then what is necessary to execute this code until you come to a place where the code works with something that you provided (this follows the assumption that the Python library is probably correct and you made a mistake).

In your specific case, the problem is most likely that `args[0]` contains a path that point to a file / executable which doesn't exist.

So check where `./config/expandlibs_exec.py`, line 311 gets `args` from and what's inside `args[0]`